# Sql query with multi return options

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to build query that return 0 or more and return -1 if Id isn't exists
For example:

```
Select Count(*)
From my table
Where id = inputId
```

I tried to use case like this:

```
Select
  CASE WHEN Count(*) >= 0 THEN Count(*) 
   ELSE -1 END
From .....
Where....
```

my issue is that 0 is valid result that mean Id exist with 0 columns,
I need to return -1 if id isn't exists

Comment: Simply `Count(*) > 0`?

Comment: `Count(*) >= 0` can *never* be false, `COUNT` will *always* return a value of 0 or more, and never `NULL`. How would the data engine `COUNT` *less than* zero rows?

Comment: Count(*) > 0 it's not working well. In case that Id exist I'm expect to 0

Comment: I need query with 3 return options 1.number that selected 2. 0 if Id exist  but 0 data 3. -1 if id isn't exists

Comment: Which 3 options? Exists (>0), and not exists (-1), but the third? (I'd keep 0 for not exists.)

Comment: How can the ID exist but you count no rows for it? We need sample data and expected results here.

Comment: Perhaps OP means id exists, but some other column is null?

Comment: Yes 0 mean id exist but other column is null or without data anyway

Comment: Use [edit] to include this "other column" in your question.  Please add some example data too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `case` *expression* to:

1. If there are values in that other column, return the count.
2. If no value in that other column, return 0 if id still exists.
3. None of the above exist, return -1.

```
select case when count(othercolumn) > 0 then count(id)   -- or perhaps "then count(othercolumn)"
            when count(id) > 0 then 0
            else -1
       end
From my table
Where id = inputId
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm reading through *several* lines here, but at a pure guess what you are *actually* want is something like:
"I want a `COUNT` of the number of rows for a specific ID where another column has a specific value. If there are no rows for the ID I want to return `-1`, however, if there are no rows where the other column has a specific value, bit there are rows for the ID, then `0` should be returned."

***If*** this is the correct interpretation, then you could use a subquery and then within the subquery `GROUP BY` the ID, even though it will still be a single distinct group; this means that if the ID doesn't exist no rows are returned. To ensure that rows *are* returned regardless of the value of the *other* column, you'll need to use conditional aggregation. This results in something like this:

```sql
SELECT ISNULL((SELECT COUNT(CASE OtherColumn WHEN @YourValue THEN 1 END)
               FROM dbo.YourTable
               WHERE ID = @ID
               GROUP BY ID),-1);
```

The `ISNULL` then means that when no rows are returned, which would result in `NULL`, `-1` is then returned.